# Everyday usage of a computer encrypted with VeraCrypt

Tags: encryption, windows, truecrypt

I'm considering adding encryption to my pc, but I wanted to ask how the daily usage of the computer changes after encrypting the Windows partition with Vera Crypt.
Ideally I would like to encrypt the system disk and the other two I have on my computer, but without the need to mount each volume every time I turn on the pc.
I just want them to be unreadable in case they are "maliciously removed" from the computer, but without becoming unpractical in daily use.

Comment: One thing that will become far more important is the maintenance of your backup schedule.

Comment: Any **full drive** encryption method runs the risk that the entire drive becomes unusable if there is an error or key is lost. My choice would be to encrypt *folders* with sensitive data. One of the most common plaints on this site is "My encrypted PC won't boot -- what do I do now?" The only reliable answer is to restore from a full disk image, if you still have the key. Otherwise, it's unlikely anything can be salvaged.